# Ajax Validation for reCaptcha

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, validation, captcha

## Background

I have a **registration form** that validates with AJAX using [jQuery Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine). The form was created using [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) and contains **[reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/)** which I implemented using [WP-reCAPTCHA](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-recaptcha/).

Just like the rest of the fields, I needed to **validate reCaptcha using AJAX** as well, that is, without refreshing the whole page. So far I managed to make it work when the Captcha didn't validate. But **when it did validate**, ie. the input was correct, the page refreshed but with an **error message** which says **'That reCAPTCHA response was incorrect'**. Thus, the form was not saved.

I tried using `console.log()` to check the output and the result is 'valid'. So I can't really tell where I went wrong.

Currently I'm testing this locally using *XAMPP*.

## The Code That I Used

**The Javascript:**

```
(function($){

  // Validate Captcha
  $.fn.validateCaptcha = function() {

    challengeField = $('input#recaptcha_challenge_field').val();
    responseField = $('input#recaptcha_response_field').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
        data: 'action=validate_captcha&recaptcha_challenge_field=' + challengeField + '&recaptcha_response_field=' + responseField,
        async: false,

        success:function(result)
          {
            //console.log( result );

            if(result != 'Valid') {

              $('#captchaError').html('<p class="error">The security code you entered did not match. Please try again.</p>');
              $captchaFlag = 'Invalid';
              Recaptcha.reload();

            } else {

              $('#memberInformation span').css({'color':'green'});
              $('#memberInformation span').html(html.message).show(3000);
              $('#captchaError').html('<p>Success!</p>');
              $captchaFlag = 'Valid';
              dataString = form.serializeArray();
              getSearchMembers(dataString);

            }
          }
      }).responseText;
  }

    $('#registerform').submit(function() {
      var form = $(this);

      if (form.validationEngine('validate')) {
        $('#memberInformation span').html('');
        form.validateCaptcha();
      } else {
        $('#memberInformation span').css('color','#ff0000').html('Please fill out required fields').show(3000);
      }
      return false;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

**The PHP:**

```
function validate_Captha() {
  $privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxx"; //<!----- private key here
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // Incorrect CAPTCHA input
    echo "Error\n";
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Please go back and try it again.\n(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    echo "Valid";
    die();
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_validate_captcha', 'validate_Captha' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_validate_captcha', 'validate_Captha' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out that **reCaptcha** actually **rejects CAPTCHAs which are submitted to their server more than once**. Since I was using the **WP-reCAPTCHA plugin**, the plugin **resubmitted** the CAPTCHA after my AJAX submission. So I just **commented out** a line from the plugin that does the submission, which is in file `recaptcha.php`, line 27:

```
$this->register_filters();
```